# Is there an iPad app for the new basecamp?

Tags: basecamp

I have been a huge fan of 37Signals project mangement tool Basecamp.  37Signals has completly overhalled the site.  Unfortunilty all the third-party apps that I have used on my ipad now don't work.

Does anyone know if there is an app that works with the "New Basecamp"

Comment: you should ask this question in their support forum

Answer (score 2):

I've not found an iPad-friendly version, but there are some iPhone ones that you can zoom to the iPad.  I know that's not exactly your question, but it was hard enough to find the iPhone ones, so I hope this helps.

- [Lodge](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lodge-basecamp-next/id533964216?mt=8)
- [SuitChamp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/suitchamp-new-basecamp-next/id553742298?mt=8)

I've used Lodge.  It's pretty good, but really wish it was on the iPad.  The other is a new one I've not seen. Here's a good place to keep an eye out:

- http://basecamp.com/extras

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

http://basecamp.com/mobile. Basecamp just recently released their iPhone App

Answer (score 0):

Basecamp just launched their official iPad app today:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/basecamp-for-ipad-official/id898020776?ls=1&mt=8